# fetch_bounces - Finished execution of Mail Reports with result: Failure, Error message: is not of type String

Tags: civimail

Scheduled Job fetch_bounces produces an Error when job execution:

Finished execution of Mail Reports with result: Failure, Error message:  is not of type String

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshots are showing two different jobs. The error is for the mail reports job. Either disable that job or set the correct parameters for it.

Comment: Okay, I understand it now and disabeld it. Thank you.